# difference between PEM_write_bio function and PEM_read_bio function in openssl

Tags: openssl

I am debugging `PEM_write_bio` and `PEM_read_bio` function in OpenSSL.

The function definition are as follows:

```
int PEM_write_bio(BIO *bp, const char *name, char *header, unsigned char *data,
                  long len)
{
    int nlen,n,i,j,outl;
    unsigned char *buf = NULL;
    EVP_ENCODE_CTX ctx;
    int reason=ERR_R_BUF_LIB;

    EVP_EncodeInit(&ctx);
    nlen=strlen(name);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ((BIO_write(bp,"-----BEGIN ",11) != 11) ||
        (BIO_write(bp,name,nlen) != nlen) ||
        (BIO_write(bp,"-----\n",6) != 6))
        goto err;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    i=strlen(header);

    if (i > 0)
    {
        if (    (BIO_write(bp,header,i) != i) ||
            (BIO_write(bp,"\n",1) != 1))
            goto err;
    }

    buf = OPENSSL_malloc(PEM_BUFSIZE*8);
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        reason=ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE;
        goto err;
    }

    i=j=0;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        n=(int)((len>(PEM_BUFSIZE*5))?(PEM_BUFSIZE*5):len);
        EVP_EncodeUpdate(&ctx,buf,&outl,&(data[j]),n);
        if ((outl) && (BIO_write(bp,(char *)buf,outl) != outl))
            goto err;
        i+=outl;
        len-=n;
        j+=n;
    }
    EVP_EncodeFinal(&ctx,buf,&outl);
    if ((outl > 0) && (BIO_write(bp,(char *)buf,outl) != outl)) goto err;
    OPENSSL_cleanse(buf, PEM_BUFSIZE*8);
    OPENSSL_free(buf);
    buf = NULL;
    if (    (BIO_write(bp,"-----END ",9) != 9) ||
        (BIO_write(bp,name,nlen) != nlen) ||
        (BIO_write(bp,"-----\n",6) != 6))
        goto err;
    return(i+outl);
err:
    if (buf) {
        OPENSSL_cleanse(buf, PEM_BUFSIZE*8);
        OPENSSL_free(buf);
    }
    PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_WRITE_BIO,reason);
    return(0);
}

int PEM_read_bio(BIO *bp, char **name, char **header, unsigned char **data,
                 long *len)
{
    EVP_ENCODE_CTX ctx;
    int end=0,i,k,bl=0,hl=0,nohead=0;
    char buf[256];
    BUF_MEM *nameB;
    BUF_MEM *headerB;
    BUF_MEM *dataB,*tmpB;

    nameB=BUF_MEM_new();
    headerB=BUF_MEM_new();
    dataB=BUF_MEM_new();
    if ((nameB == NULL) || (headerB == NULL) || (dataB == NULL))
    {
        BUF_MEM_free(nameB);
        BUF_MEM_free(headerB);
        BUF_MEM_free(dataB);
        PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
        return(0);
    }

    buf[254]='\0';
    for (;;)
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (i <= 0)
        {
            PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,PEM_R_NO_START_LINE);
            goto err;
        }

        while ((i >= 0) && (buf[i] <= ' ')) i--;
        buf[++i]='\n'; buf[++i]='\0';

        if (strncmp(buf,"-----BEGIN ",11) == 0)
        {
            i=strlen(&(buf[11]));

            if (strncmp(&(buf[11+i-6]),"-----\n",6) != 0)
                continue;
            if (!BUF_MEM_grow(nameB,i+9))
            {
                PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
                goto err;
            }
            memcpy(nameB->data,&(buf[11]),i-6);
            nameB->data[i-6]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    hl=0;
    if (!BUF_MEM_grow(headerB,256))
    { PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE); goto err; }
    headerB->data[0]='\0';
    for (;;)
    {
        i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
        if (i <= 0) break;

        while ((i >= 0) && (buf[i] <= ' ')) i--;
        buf[++i]='\n'; buf[++i]='\0';

        if (buf[0] == '\n') break;
        if (!BUF_MEM_grow(headerB,hl+i+9))
        { PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE); goto err; }
        if (strncmp(buf,"-----END ",9) == 0)
        {
            nohead=1;
            break;
        }
        memcpy(&(headerB->data[hl]),buf,i);
        headerB->data[hl+i]='\0';
        hl+=i;
    }

    bl=0;
    if (!BUF_MEM_grow(dataB,1024))
    { PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE); goto err; }
    dataB->data[0]='\0';
    if (!nohead)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
            if (i <= 0) break;

            while ((i >= 0) && (buf[i] <= ' ')) i--;
            buf[++i]='\n'; buf[++i]='\0';

            if (i != 65) end=1;
            if (strncmp(buf,"-----END ",9) == 0)
                break;
            if (i > 65) break;
            if (!BUF_MEM_grow_clean(dataB,i+bl+9))
            {
                PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
                goto err;
            }
            memcpy(&(dataB->data[bl]),buf,i);
            dataB->data[bl+i]='\0';
            bl+=i;
            if (end)
            {
                buf[0]='\0';
                i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
                if (i <= 0) break;

                while ((i >= 0) && (buf[i] <= ' ')) i--;
                buf[++i]='\n'; buf[++i]='\0';

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tmpB=headerB;
        headerB=dataB;
        dataB=tmpB;
        bl=hl;
    }
    i=strlen(nameB->data);
    if (    (strncmp(buf,"-----END ",9) != 0) ||
        (strncmp(nameB->data,&(buf[9]),i) != 0) ||
        (strncmp(&(buf[9+i]),"-----\n",6) != 0))
    {
        PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,PEM_R_BAD_END_LINE);
        goto err;
    }

    EVP_DecodeInit(&ctx);
    i=EVP_DecodeUpdate(&ctx,
                       (unsigned char *)dataB->data,&bl,
                       (unsigned char *)dataB->data,bl);
    if (i < 0)
    {
        PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,PEM_R_BAD_BASE64_DECODE);
        goto err;
    }
    i=EVP_DecodeFinal(&ctx,(unsigned char *)&(dataB->data[bl]),&k);
    if (i < 0)
    {
        PEMerr(PEM_F_PEM_READ_BIO,PEM_R_BAD_BASE64_DECODE);
        goto err;
    }
    bl+=k;

    if (bl == 0) goto err;
    *name=nameB->data;
    *header=headerB->data;
    *data=(unsigned char *)dataB->data;
    *len=bl;
    OPENSSL_free(nameB);
    OPENSSL_free(headerB);
    OPENSSL_free(dataB);
    return(1);
err:
    BUF_MEM_free(nameB);
    BUF_MEM_free(headerB);
    BUF_MEM_free(dataB);
    return(0);
}
```

I have observed that while writing private key `PEM_write_bio` writes string `------BEGIN <name> -----\n` to the file according to their length:

```
if ((BIO_write(bp,"-----BEGIN ",11) != 11) ||
    (BIO_write(bp,name,nlen) != nlen) ||
    BIO_write(bp,"-----\n",6) != 6))
        goto err;
```

But while reading the private key using function `PEM_read_bio` it is reading value in chunks of 254:

```
i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
```

Due to this I am facing a Problem. I could not understand why it is reading file by block of 254.

Comment: Could you please describe what problem are you facing? I don't know any standard PEM header which is longer than 254 bytes.

Comment: Actually When function  Reads 254 bytes first time .  After                          if (strncmp(&(buf[11+i-6]),"-----\n",6) != 0)
 continue;

Comment: Could you please also post the first line (header) of your PEM file?

Comment: The above condition is not satisfying.

Comment: -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: After that base64 encoded data started.

Comment: Did you change EOL (Windows/Unix) format in your file? It would be also great if you could post calling context - parameters passed to the PEM_read_bio() function.

Comment: Actually this file is stored in the flash memory of micro controller and data is stored in the form of bytes here new line character(\n) also get stored only as 0x0A hex value in flash memory

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. The difference between `PEM_read_*` and `PEM_write_*` is fairly obvious, so I don't believe that's why you posted a question.

Comment: The way of reading the private key from file is different from writing the private key to file.while reading it reads the data from the file in chunks of 254 bytes I am asking why it reads data in chunks of 254 bytes instead of any other number?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    buf[254]='\0';
>    for (;;)
>    {
>        i=BIO_gets(bp,buf,254);
>        ...
>    }
> ```
>
> Due to this I am facing a Problem. I could not understand why it is reading file by block of 254.

Well, it seems 254 is arbitrary. You could make or 32, 64, 128 or 512.

I would expected to see a value closer to a disk sector size, like 1024 or 4096. At minimum, I would expect it to be a power of 2.

However, there is an upper limit on the line encountered in the field under certain circumstances. One of the circumstances would be S/MIME and reading through a `BIO` with `BIO_gets`. In RFC 1421, [Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail: Part I: Message Encryption and Authentication Procedures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421):

```
4.3.1 Constraints
...
    2.  Text lines, delimited by the character pair <CR><LF>, must
        be no more than 1000 characters long.
...
```

I'm not sure the restriction applies in your case, but its the closest I could find to a limit or reason.

I guess you should change it to whatever suits your taste.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Question arises why same concept is not applied during writing?